# Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file with apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates, source

Whenever I execute apt-get update on my ubuntu 14.04, I get this error !

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

Anyone knows how to fix it ?

Comment: please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/677904/edit)  and add output of `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: no need, fixed the problem with changing the mirror server.

Answer (score 1):

Change the mirror server from the "Software & Updates" under "Ubuntu Software"